# zsh completion-expansion & cursor position

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Assume there are three dirs: `abc adc aec`

I want to type `cd dc`, press `Tab` and get `cd adc` (trailing `/` is not important) completion.

Is it possible? What is the simplest way to achieve this behaviour?

I can move cursor to `d` inside `dc` and then press `Tab`, `zsh` will complete; but this is not convenient at all.

Answer (score 1):

#### In your `~/.zshrc`:

1. Make sure you're enabling `compinit`:

   ```
   autoload -U compinit
   compinit -i
   ```
2. Enable tab-completion in-word:

   ```
   setopt complete_in_word
   ```
3. Shift the cursor to the end of the word after tab-completion.

   ```
   setopt always_to_end
   ```

Those four lines (or even just [`1`] and [`2`]) were all I needed in an empty `~/.zshrc` to enable this behaviour.